# Android: where in code super class must be calling

Tags: java, android, superclass

What is right?

```
@Override
protected void onPause() {
    // myCode
    super.onPause();
}
```

or

```
@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    // myCode
}
```

Comment: call the superclass function first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This entirely depends on whether you want your code to be run before or after the super implementation. There's no right or wrong.

See these two examples:

```
// prepend instructions to onPause
@Override
protected void onPause() {
    Log.debug("About to pause application...");
    super.onPause();
}
```

vs

```
// append instructions to onPause
@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    Log.debug("Just paused the application...");
}
```

In the specific case of `onPause` however, you should always call `super.onPause` first. See [Pausing and Resuming an Activity](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/pausing.html).

Comment: I finally understand it